# Git: maintain 2 branches with 99% of similar code

Tags: java, git, maven, merge, branching-and-merging

I'm working on a Java project with Maven, where I need to deploy very often to two different weblogic environments. The only differences between these 2 deployments are a bunch of changes in these 2 files: `pom.xml` and `weblogic.xml` files. The rest of the files are the same.

We're creating 2 GIT branches for this: `dev` & `parallel-dev`.

But we're having many problems maintaining and merging the changes between these two branches.

All the changes are done in `parallel-dev` branch, and once this code is reviewed and approved, we're merging it to `dev` branch, except those two files that don't need to be merged (unless the pom version is modified - in that case we need to merge just the version change but not the rest of changes in pom.xml). This is kind of messy.

I think this method is pretty confusing and can be improved, but can't really see how. I'd love to just keep one branch for this process and avoid all those crazy merges that we're facing.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

-- EDIT --

The difference in the pom.xml is just a different profile for parallel-dev branch:

```
<profiles>
<profile>
  <id>parallel-dev</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
  </activation>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>env.properties</include>
          <include>more.properties</include>
          ...
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>env.properties</exclude>
          <exclude>more.properties</exclude>
          ...
        </excludes>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
  </build>
</profile>
```

In `weblogic.xml` the difference is the context-root name and a library reference (this lib also has parallel-dev and dev branches).

Comment: maybe declare the files in .gitignore so they don't get commited

Comment: @Lino The `pom.xml`? No! This 100% needs to be committed.

Comment: could you keep the pom.xml and weblogic.xml separate - and just have one branch for the rest of the code?

Comment: can you please post your pom.xml and mark the differences?

Comment: It might be easier to just make a copy of both files with a slightly different name, and just change the ones you need to the correct filenames, when you need them. Although that might be an annoying approach :-)

Comment: What kind of changes in pom file? Dependencies? Than make two different modules which have different dependencies...

Comment: I've edited the question explaining the differences in those two files.

Comment: Which in the end means you have only differences in properties files for different environments...http://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin

Comment: A worthwhile read: https://12factor.net/

Comment: I would strongly advice to move away from configuration management as Git branches. Have used it in the past and it always turned out to be PITA. I myself use gradle, which allows you to script any configuration change to happen at build time as a function of env variable value, build flags, etc. Not sure whether you can do this in Maven natively, but as a last resort you can always have a pre-processing standalone script.

Comment: Two options to look into specific to git (vs changing your project) are `git update-index` and git rerere (but require a more in depth analysis of your needs) https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Isolate the changes you made to those two files in the `dev` branch.
2. Destroy the `dev` branch and recreate it from the `parallel-dev` branch.
3. Reapply the changes on the `dev` branch in a new commit.

Now, whenever new development happens on the `parallel-dev` branch, switch to the `dev` branch and do:

`git rebase parallel-dev`

(or the equivalent operation in your GUI tool).
This will reset the `dev` branch to the newest version of `parallel-dev` and reapply the isolated change to those two xml files.

If the change to `parallel-dev` happened to overlap with the isolated changes you will still have merge conflicts, but otherwise you should be good to go. (Although I would double-check the .xml files just to be safe)

Answer (score 0):

I would create two Maven submodules in your project, keeping the code in the parent module but the different configurations in the submodules. This way you don't need two different branches, and so you get rid of all those related merging conflicts.

Relevant part of parent POM:

```xml
<modules>
    <module>dev</module>
    <module>paralleldev</module>
</modules>
```

And in the sub-modules you just need to create the specific POM and the `src/main/resources` folder and in the POM include the sources from the parent. The submodule-relevant part:

```xml
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>../src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

You can do even more with the Maven Compiler Plugin—take a look here: [Guide to Using Maven when You Can't Use the Conventions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html)